# Why can't I remove div tag from variable?

Tags: android

I'm trying remove div tag from variable using [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) library but It's not working with me.

*Code*

```
String test = "<div>hey</div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(test);
doc.select("div").remove();
Log.w("log",test);
```

*The result*

```
2019-08-30 19:25:24.206 314-3434/com.test.app W/log: <div>hey</div>
```

Comment: Try this Elements divs = doc.select("div"); divs.remove(divs.size());

Comment: You're printing the input String `test`. Try to print out `doc` instead of `test`.

Comment: Could you provide an example of input-output or specify, what result is expected?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use `String.replace()` method?
Eg:

```
String test = "<div>Hey<div>";
String newTest = test.replace("<div>", "");
```

Or try this to remove using JSoup,

```
 doc.getElementsByTag("div").remove();
```

Comment: I want with Jsoup

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to remove `<div>` and `</div>` from your String you could just use `replaceAll("<div>", "")` and similar method for the closing tag.

If you want to use Jsoup you could just get your string back using some of them after you remove tags or get the document back to the string after performing operations:

```
String output = doc.toString();
```

or

```
String output = doc.html;
```